# Change background script does not work.(external js file)

Tags: javascript, html

So i put in a script for changing background that i used before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>KeKeyDesigned</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<script src="js/JSS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="topLeft" class="left">
<div id="one" onclick="change('darkgrey')"> </div>
<div id="two" onclick="change('white')"> </div>
</div>
```

The script inside the file is this:

```
function change ('color') {
document.body.style.background = color ;
}
```

But honestly it doesnt work at all.And when i pressed f12 on my chrome i noticed that instead of reading it as though it was in head the browser showed the script tag as though it was in the body,not sure if  that means aynthing.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you used it before successfully. Look at your console for syntax errors, particularly on the line `function change('color')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't hard code color as a string in your function i.e. color in your function could be called chips, pepper etc you get my point, your passing it over to your function.

try the below:

```
function change (color) {
  document.body.style.background = color ;
}
```

working example

```js
function change (color) {
    document.body.style.background = color ;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="topLeft" class="left">
    <div id="one" onclick="change('darkgrey')"> click me for dark grey </div>
    <div id="two" onclick="change('white')"> click me for white </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,you were right,putting args of a function inbrakets was the problem.

Comment: great please tick the green arrow and mark it as answered so anyone else with the same issue as you can find the answer quickly :) @NikitaCebotari